# Optional Javascript Execution based on Media Queries

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I'm trying to figure out how I can optionally run a block of javascript based on the current device/media query. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and have essentially two versions of media queries:

```
@media (min-width: 980px) { ... } <!-- Desktops -->
@media (max-width: 979px) { ... } <!-- Smaller screens/tablets/phones -->
```

I have a map that I generate, but am not showing it in the mobile/small screen version forb andwidth reasons. Yet, the javascript still executes in the background even though you can't see it on the mobile screen. So, I'm trying to find a way in javascript where I can do something like:

```
// Imaginary function
var screenType = getScreenType();

if(screenType == 1) {
   // Load map
}
```

I've [read about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861802/javascript-and-media-queries) people setting CSS properties to specific values in their media queries and then trying to find that element in the DOM based on the CSS property, but there has got to be  a better way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using javascript for that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if (screen.width < 980) { 

document.write('<link href="UrLowRes.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>');

} else { 

document.write('<link href="UrlHighRes.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>');

} 

</script>
```

Comment: Interesting, I think this will be an acceptable solution. Thanks.

Comment: If your window width can be resized, you might need to add monitoring for window width changes?

Comment: My primary concern is not wasting bandwidth on mobile devices, so in this case width changes are unlikely to affect my goal.

Comment: @jfriend00: screen.width or screen.height deal with the size of the display, not the size of the window. The size of the display is fixed by the hardware and cannot change.

Comment: @frenchie - what about when the device is rotated?

Comment: @jfriend00: good point. I think the OP should check for that: either the values return the same regardless of the orientation of use something like if (Math.Min(screen.width, screen.height)) {...}

Comment: This is sub-par as an answer. @yeradis answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18174378/632333 is the way to go!

Answer (score 32):

The current accepted answer is not good enough, you should check **window.matchMedia**

You can detect viewport dimension changes, but you must calculate factors such as orientation and aspect ratios and there is no guarantee our calculation will match our browser assumptions when it applies media query rules.

I mean, you can calculate X, but your browser assumption can be Y. 
So i think is better to use same browser rules, and window.matchMedia does it

```
var jmediaquery = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 480px)" )
if (jmediaquery.matches) {
    // window width is at least 480px
}
else {
    // window width is less than 480px
}
```

You can even receive query notification using a listener

```
var jmediaquery = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");
jmediaquery.addListener(handleOrientationChange);
handleOrientationChange(jmediaquery);

function handleOrientationChange(jmediaquery) {
    if (jmediaquery.matches) {
        // orientation changed
    }
}
```

If you no longer need to receive notifications about changes simply call removeListener()

```
jmediaquery.removeListener(handleOrientationChange);
```

Comment: Good Idea! Thanks for keeping this question up to date.

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't let you check the result if you resize your browser window, so for developing purpose, this answer is better. thks!

Comment: great insight, +1

Comment: This is great to know! Thanks!

Comment: That's how we do it! +1

Answer (score 12):

You might find the Enquire.js library helpful:

http://wickynilliams.github.com/enquire.js/

CSS-Tricks article: http://css-tricks.com/enquire-js-media-query-callbacks-in-javascript/

Comment: Very useful library, although I'm thinking in my particular instance, pure Javascript is probably the lightest weight solution. Thanking for pointing out Enquire though, I will probably use it in future projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can also using a plugin called minwidth:

```
minwidth(940, function () {
  //do whatever you need
});
```

But it only works when the page loads not when resizing..

http://edenspiekermann.com/en/blog/responsive-javascript-helpers