# Toggle dropdown when screen size < 1200

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I write such function which on screen with width > 1200 have hover effect and show menu

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var width = $(window).innerWidth();
    dropDown(width);
});

var dropDown = function(width){
    if(width > 1200){
        $(".dropdown").hover(function() {
                $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).fadeIn("fast");
                $(this).toggleClass('open');
                $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");
            }, function() {
                $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).fadeOut("fast");
                $(this).toggleClass('open');
                $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");
            }
        );
    }
};
```

The problem is when i refresh page on mobile size - all looks fine, but then change size of window > 1200px and then change size of window < 1200px my dropDown show when i hover, but i don't need it, it must open only when i click. Where is the problem? What i should do?

My html

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">DROPDOWN <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: You'll be better of using [media queries](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18477316/542251) rather than javascript. (Providing your targeting [browsers that support media queries](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-media-resolution))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've not removed the hover handler when the window is less that 1200 wide, so the event handler still exists and works.  The `else` part of the `if` statement below will fix that for you...

```
var openDropDown = function(el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    $('.dropdown-menu', $el).stop( true, true ).fadeIn("fast");
    $el.toggleClass('open');
    $('b', $el).toggleClass("caret caret-up");
};
var closeDropDown = function(el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    $('.dropdown-menu', $el).stop( true, true ).fadeOut("fast");
    $el.toggleClass('open');
    $('b', $el).toggleClass("caret caret-up");
};

var dropDown = function(width){
    if(width > 1200){
        $(".dropdown")
            .off("click")
            .hover(function() {
                openDropDown(this);
            }, function() {
                closeDropDown(this);
            });
    }
    else {
        $(".dropdown")
            .off("mouseenter mouseleave")
            .on("click", function() {
                if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
                    closeDropDown(this);
                }
                else {
                    openDropDown(this);
                }
            });
    }
};
```

I've also moved the code to open and close the dropdown into separate functions so that it can be reused.  I then added a click handler to make the dropdown work when clicked when the window is < 1200 wide.

Comment: U save my time ) Thank you!

Comment: The next problem is that the dropdown will not open after else-function i you click on it

Comment: @Zorken17, solution: `else {
        $dropDowns.off( "mouseenter mouseleave" );
        $dropDowns.on('click', function(){
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).toggle();
        });
    }`

Comment: Sorry - I missed that.  I'll amend it to suit.

Comment: @Archer i have an error, when use your code - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Comment: Okay - it was a choice to use bind.  I'll pass a reference to the element instead.  Give me a minute

Comment: Try that now and see how you get on.  Obviously the open and close functions need a reference to the dropdown that's hovered or clicked, so the event handlers now pass that in as the `el` parameter.  That should solve the previous bind problem.

Comment: Great.  Glad to help :)